# Употребление деепричастий в безличных предложениях

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, деепричастный-оборот

Допустимо ли такое предложение:
 "Однако попав под командование строгого вояки Пономарева, Долговушину пришлось не просто отсиживаться в тылу?"

Comment: На эту же тему см. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432766/%d0%9e-%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a0%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0

Answer (score 3):

Цитата из того же параграфа:

```
 Обычно употребление деепричастного оборота, не  выражающего  
 действия    подлежащего, т.е. в безличном   предложении, возможно, 
 если     производитель действия обозначен инфинитивом,  причастием 
 или      другим деепричастием
```

Предложенное предложение не удовлетворяет этим условиям, потому что добавочное действие не вполне является действием субъекта,это скорее его состояние в результате какого-то воздействия: отсиживается Долговушин, а вот "попал"="оказался в результате чего-то", он не субъект, а лицо страдающее, объект.

К этому же безличному предложению возможно присоединить другой деепричастный оборот:

Долговушину пришлось не просто отсиживаться в тылу,отдыхая и отъедаясь, а ...

Вот здесь условия соблюдены:производитель действия обозначен инфинитивом. И отсиживался, и отдыхал, и отъедался Долговушин.

Данное же предложение всё-таки стилистически некорректно, носит просторечный характер. Его следует перестроить: "Однако, когда Долговушин попал под командование строгого вояки Пономарева, ему пришлось не просто отсиживаться в тылу...

Comment: Людмила, но у Розенталя всё-таки "стилистически неоправданно", а не "некорректно". Это совсем не тот уровень недопустимости.

Comment: Смысл один : употреблять нежелательно, если считаешь себя грамотным человеком и хочешь говорить литературным языком. Для неграмотных и в устном бытовом разговоре - пойдёт.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, но я все-таки полагаю, что значение у слов "неоправданно" и "некорректно" принципиально разное. "Я потратил деньги неоправданно" и "я потратил деньги некорректно".

Answer (score 2):

**По Розенталю,** такое предложение **допускается**: Однако попав под командование строгого вояки Пономарева, Долговушину **пришлось** **не просто отсиживаться** в тылу.

Долговушину **ПРИШЛОСЬ не просто ОТСИЖИВАТЬСЯ** (когда?), **ПОПАВ** под командование (= когда он попал под командование). Здесь  в безличном предложении деепричастный оборот относится к инфинитиву.

**Розенталь:** [§212. Деепричастные обороты](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm#%D0%B7_02)

В ряде случаев возможно употребление деепричастного оборота, не выражающего действия подлежащего:

2) в безличном предложении **при инфинитиве**, например: **ПРИХОДИЛОСЬ РАБОТАТЬ** в трудных условиях, **НЕ ИМЕЯ** в течение многих недель ни одного свободного дня для отдыха.

**Одинаковые  формы У Розенталя и в приведённом примере: безличная форма вспомогательного глагола + инфинитив. Даже вспомогательный глагол один и тот же.**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Действие, обозначаемое деепричастием (деепричастным оборотом), относится, как правило, **к подлежащему данного предложения**. У Розенталя указаны **допустимые исключения**, но в современном языке такие конструкции уже не кажутся безупречными, и по возможности их следует избегать.

**Это общая тенденция развития грамматики**, так как раньше допускались  варианты, которые сейчас считаются **отступлением от нормы**, например: Поселившись теперь в деревне, его мечта и идеал были в том, чтобы воскресить ту форму жизни, которая была при деде (Л. Толстой).

Comment: Здесь деепричастный оборот грамматически относится **не** к инфинитиву, а к глаголу "пришлось" (_попав, пришлось_), с которым, в свою очередь, связан имеющийся инфинитив. У Розенталя же в допустимом примере связь такая: "... _работать, не имея_...".

Comment: Пришлось отсиживаться - составное глагольное сказуемое, пришлось - это ВСПОМОГАТЕЛЬНЫЙ модальный глагол, ОСНОВНЫМ глаголом является инфинитив "отсиживаться". Сравнить: Он был вынужден не просто отсиживаться.  К инфинитиву и относится оборот. Приходилось работать, пришлось отсиживаться - одно и то же.

Comment: Sibylla, сочетание ***безличной формы вспомогательного глагола с интфинитивом - это не "инфинитив"***. У вас грубая смысловая ошибка. инфинитив был бы "приходиться отсиживаться", он, наверное, и не встречается в живой речи...

Comment: Это сообщение заслуживало минуса, удаленного модератором. Причина изложена в комментариях, Автор просто запутался в простейших понятиях.

Comment: @Sharon Хотел задать вопрос на эту же тему и нашел несколько вопросов-ответов, в том числе и этот, поэтому спрошу здесь. "*Взглянув однажды в зеркало, мне захотелось написать о волосах*". Это предложение нормативное, составлено по такой же схеме?  Вспомогательный глагол, инфинитив, и даже есть деятель, правда не в им. падеже.  Или лучше избегать такого построения предложения?

Comment: @Роман Корнеев Очевидно, что это ненормативное предложение, сравнить: Можно написать о волосах. взглянув однажды в зеркало. Но нужно подумать, что с ним не так. Замена: Можно написать о волосах, если взглянуть в зеркало. Но ненормативно: Мне захотелось написать о волосах, если взглянуть в зеркало.  Но я пока не знаю, как это лучше сформулировать. У Розенталя: "Если же в безличном предложении нет инфинитива, к которому мог бы относиться деепричастный оборот, то употребление последнего стилистически неоправданно", Значит, надо доказать, что оборот не относится к инфинитиву.

Answer (score 0):

Розенталь трактует такие конструкции как стилистически неоправданные. То есть возможные, но нежелательные.

www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm §212

> Если же в безличном предложении нет инфинитива, к которому мог бы
>   относиться деепричастный оборот, то употребление последнего
>   стилистически неоправданно, например. «Уезжая из родного города, мне
>   стало грустно»; «Прочитав вторично рукопись, редактору показалось, что
>   она нуждается в серьезной доработке».

Это тот же источник, но не тот случай, о котором говорит Sibylla, здесь принципиально иная мотивация - глагол в "безличной" форме.

У нас деепричастный оборот не относится к инфинитиву. Там инфинитив относится к вспомогательному глаголу "пришлось", а сам деепричастный оборот - ко всему сказуемому "пришлось [не просто] отсиживаться".

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61063/discussion-on-answer-by------).