# О норме употребления деепричастных оборотов, отнесенных к инфинитиву (по Розенталю)

Tags: деепричастный-оборот

Вопрос следующий: **Насколько четко правила Розенталя регулируют употребление деепричастных оборотов, отнесенных к инфинитиву?**  Можно ли считать, что норме в большей степени соответствуют **деепричастия несовершенного вида в препозиции относительно инфинитива?**

Кстати, именно эти формы приводит в качестве примера  Людмила в своем ответе: **Долговушину пришлось не просто отсиживаться в тылу,отдыхая и отъедаясь**... [Употребление деепричастий в безличных предложениях | Русский язык stackexchange.com](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432754/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85)

1) Когда-то Лев Толстой писал: **Поселившись теперь в деревне, его мечта и идеал были в том, чтобы воскресить ту форму жизни, которая была при деде**.

Это обычный литературный текст (не просторечие персонажа), значит, тогда  такое употребление деепричастий считалось нормой (то, что сейчас называют галлицизмами). Но постепенно галлицизмы (вероятно, вместе с французским языком) сошли на нет, и сегодня подобные конструкции на слух  не воспринимаются и противоречат норме.

**2) А вот норма какова (у Розенталя)?** [§212. Деепричастные обороты | evartist.narod.ru](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm#%D0%B7_02)

Наилучший вариант – это когда    действие, обозначаемое деепричастием (деепричастным оборотом), относится к подлежащему данного предложения, например: Подведя итоги прений, председатель собрания отметил общность взглядов докладчика и участников совещания».

Но тут встают вопросы: 
а) Грамматическое подлежащее не совпадает с производителем действия в **страдательных конструкциях**: Получив признание широких читательских масс, книга была переиздана.  Здесь употребление деепричастного оборота не отвечает норме.
б)  В безличных предложениях **нет грамматического подлежащего**, но п**роизводитель действия** может обозначаться дополнением.

**3) Как же сформулировать норму?**

Действие (причем активное) должен совершать один и тот же производитель, в идеале это действие выражается сказуемым.  Но допускается варианты с **инфинитивом** (с другими глагольными формами?), например такие:  **Отряду  пришлось двигаться по бездорожью, пересекая овраги  и небольшие речки** (вспомогательный глагол с модальным значением). б) **Ему сказали  идти напрямик,  переходя оживленные дороги только ночью** (инфинитив в роли дополнения).

Обратим внимание на **несовершенный вид деепричастных оборотов, расположенных после инфинитива**, они играют роль  обстоятельства образа действия.

4) А теперь рассмотрим уже знакомое предложение: **Однако попав под командование строгого вояки Пономарева, Долговушину пришлось не просто отсиживаться в тылу.**

**Звучит не лучшим образом, но что в нем не так?** Производитель действия один и тот же: Долговушин попал под командование, и он же не просто отсиживался. Но вот деепричастие здесь **совершенного вида и находится в препозиции,** в этом случае оно является **обстоятельством времени.**  Такие конструкции уже плохо воспринимаются на слух, кажутся ненормативными, вот только  **признак подобных предложений обозначен у Розенталя неясно.**

5) И еще одно предложение у Розенталя читается не лучшим образом: **«Автору было предложено внести в рукопись дополнения, учитывая изменения, происшедшие в жизни общества за последнее время».**  Автор ли должен учитывать или это обстоятельственный оборот вида «в связи с изменениями…»?

Может,  с грамматикой  что-то не так?  Здесь  **значительно распространенное  предложение и разный вид у  глагола и деепричастия**. Попробуем изменить:  **Автору предложили составлять тексты, учитывая современные нормы письма**. Так вроде бы звучит нормально.

Comment: Вопрос сформулируйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: На эту тему см. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432754/%d0%a3%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С точки зрения дилетанта.

Деепричастный оборот отвечает на вопросы *что делая? что сделав?*

Легитимные причастные обороты:

- двигаться (что делая?), пересекая овраги и небольшие речки
- идти (что делая?), переходя оживленные дороги только ночью списка
- внести (что делая?), учитывая изменения

Проблема только с предложением:

**Однако попав под командование строгого вояки Пономарева, Долговушину пришлось не просто отсиживаться в тылу**

Нелегитимно: пришлось (нельзя поставить вопрос *что делая?*) попав под командование строгого вояки Пономарева

Comment: По Розенталю это не "нелигитимно", а неоправданно стилистически. Впрочем, на фоне всего остального, это детали. Ві отвечаете на какой-то вопрос, который не задан. А на самом деле тут и копья ломать нечего. Деепричастный оборот несет обстоятельства действия. Во всех случаях, когда это именно так,  ДО допустим, Розенталь только формализовал и скрупулезно перечислил все условия для того чтобы это было именно обстоятелстом действия. Когда же такой связи нет (типичный случай - действия разных лиц), ДО грамматически некорректен или сомнителен.

Comment: В чем вопрос-то? Почему Sibylla не нравится одно сочетание, но нравится другое?

Comment: В принципе   Вы правы, я бы   только добавила, что "попав (совершенный вид)  под командование" имеет значение  обстоятельства времени, а не образа действия.  Деепричастие совершенного вида обозначает предшествующее, а не одновременное действие, поэтому такая форма кажется не вполне нормативной.